# Can I patent an application of a popular technology?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications

**Can I patent an application of a popular technology?**

Let's say Blockchain is a very popular technology nowadays and there are hundreds of applications proposed and ongoing in many different domains like in, finance and medical sectors. Now, when I come across a new idea of a particular application of the Blockchain technology like, resolving an existing problem (never been addressed for distributed solution) with a distributed system using Blockchain where several solutions might exist for centralized system.

**Can my idea be patented reasonably?**

---

<sup>NB: I am new in this site, please correct me if my question is not addressed properly. I will modify it.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A (technological) solution to a problem needs to be novel and non-obvious(/inventive) as a whole. Basically every solution is composed of known components.

The specific answer depends on many factors. In general, if you use an existing technology in a new field, the question is, would it have been obvious to try this solution.

While going into details of non-obviousness in patents is a topic for a book and not an answer here, if you, as a technically skilled person, think it wasn't too obvious but could have been tried, you are probably well beyond the needed non-obviousness. Getting a patent for something is in most cases a lot easier than people would expect.